# Unable to upload files; file upload modal displays CP Home

Tags: expressionengine

I am tearing my hair out with a file weird file upload issue that I have never run into before. For some reason I’m unable to upload images via the file manager (both in the file manager itself and if I upload with a custom field using the “file” fieldtype). Strangely, if I add files directly to any of the file upload directories, and sync the files, everything works fine.

After selecting the file and hitting “upload file” (see 01_choose_file.jpg) the modal window displays the CP homepage in an iframe (see 02_upload_progress.jpg).

Has anyone else seen this? Does anyone know how I can start troubleshooting this?

Background Info:

- I’m running EECMS v2.5.2 - Build Date: 20120606 in MAMP (only 2 out of 15 sites I have set up locally are not working)
- I have tried uploading images/files using the latest versions of Chrome, Chrome Canary, Safari, and Firefox (OS X 10.7.5)
- This issue is showing up on the two latest sites I’ve started dev’ing locally on, no other site (locally or otherwise)

Things I’ve done:

- Checked Apache/PHP error logs; they don’t show anything
- Confirmed file upload paths and file upload directory settings are correct – I can sync files that i manually move into the various file upload directories
- Permissions are fine; image manipulations and thumbnail creation work fine if I manually add files to the upload directories
- Tested various other 2.5.2 installs I dev on locally and they work fine (settings on these two new sites are identical to sites that work)
- Only a handful of native add-ons are enabled
- “Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files?” setting Yes or No does not make a difference

Huge thanks for any help!

I can't post images so here are links to the images:
01_choose_file.jpg: http://expressionengine.com/?ACT=51&fid=105&aid=16264_Jiof3p0V1gfEEFrpC55G&board_id=5

02_upload_progress.jpg: http://expressionengine.com/?ACT=51&fid=105&aid=16265_mjGH02xK2fIFZJI6kruP&board_id=5

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling various add-ons to see if something is breaking? It's rarely the core causing problems, and usually some attempt to modify behavior that causes issues. I would try to rule out this before digging deeper.

Comment: Yeah, I am down to just "Channel" & "jQuery"... but I am seeing this in the network profiler http://d.pr/i/aDiK

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have sorted this out. I went back through to make sure I disabled all third party add-ons and I had forgotten to uninstall the "Quickee" extension http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/quickee. For now that seems to be the culprit.

I've submitted the bug to Matt (the developer) and it should be patched up soon.

Comment: It was indeed my fault :) It is fixed now: https://github.com/mattfordham/Quickee

Comment: No one's fault! Thank you for the super quick turnaround on the fix. Well played sir!

Answer (score 3):

The ExpressionEngine filemanager sends out a AJAX POST request to the following URL:

```
http://YOUR_ADMIN_CP_URL?S=0&D=cp&C=content_files_modal&M=upload_file
```

Have you tried loading that URL yourself? You should get a page like this

[image: file upload URL]

But maybe EE is trying to POST to a different URL. You can find it by uploading a large file and while it's uploading using **Firebug** and in the **Network** tab at the bottom of the list you will find the URL EE is posting to
[image: firebug network tab]

Comment: I can load the URL myself and it works (I get the error page).

And it seems to be posting to the correct URL but I am seeing this when I load the filemanager: http://d.pr/i/aDiK

Comment: After some more digging it looks like something is preventing the "POST"